# Rank a numeric column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to rank a column called `Number` after grouping by the column `ID` but the ranking would be done only if `Variable_1` is `True`.  If `Variable_1` is `False`, assign directly to the new column `Rank` the highest rank : `1`

```
data={'ID':["A","A","B","C","D","D"], 'Variable_1':[True,True,False,False,True,True], 'Number': [10,20,5,6,100,90]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I tried to do the following but did not work:

```
 df["Rank"] = np.where(df.Variable_1, df.groupby(["ID"])[["Number"]].rank(method='dense', ascending=False), 1)
```

This is the expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first set column `Rank` to `1` and use [`pandas.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and compute rank. At the end write rank for those rows that have `Variable_1 == True` with [`pandas.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html).

```
df['Rank'] = 1
res = df.groupby('ID')['Number'].rank(ascending=False)
df['Rank'] = df['Rank'].mask(df['Variable_1'], res)
print(df)
```

---

```
  ID  Variable_1  Number  Rank
0  A        True      10     2
1  A        True      20     1
2  B       False       5     1
3  C       False       6     1
4  D        True     100     1
5  D        True      90     2
```